# ReactJS Koans Grocery-list part 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React using the ReactJS Koans by Arkency. I am stuck on exercise 05-Challenge-GroceryList-part-1.jsx. My code brings up the list correctly when I run it on the server, but when I run the tests I get "1) There should be an unordered list of groceries... AssertionError: GroceryItem should render only text inside < li > tag. This text should contain only grocery item name." Any ideas? Without their comments, my code is as follows:

```
var React = require("react");
class GroceryList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groceries: [ { name: "Apples" } ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    for(var index = 0; index < this.state.groceries.length; index++) {
      groceriesComponents.push(
          <GroceryListItem
            grocery={this.state.groceries[index]}
          />
      );
    }

    return (
      <ul>
        {groceriesComponents}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class GroceryListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <li key={this.props}>
          {this.props}
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GroceryListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <li key={this.props}>
          {this.props.grocery.name}
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Try that. Notice that you're using `this.props` which won't print the name of the grocery...You have to reference the `prop`. Like above.

This bit of code is actually going into the grocery prop and grabbing the name value `{this.props.grocery.name}`.

Try just adding the name to the grocery prop:

```
groceriesComponents.push(
          <GroceryListItem
            grocery={this.state.groceries[index].name}
          />
      );
```

Then in your component you would do `{this.props.grocery}` To me it sounds like the program that's validating your code wants it to look exactly the same as theres.

Comment: When I use `{this.props.grocery.name}`, I get the right value to display in the browser, but the test suite still gives me the same error message. If you want to see the test suite its available at https://github.com/neallred/reactjs_koans/tree/neallred

Comment: @neallred - Hmmmm, that sounds like it's expecting you to write the exact same code as theres. Look at my edit

Comment: Oops! Your first solution worked fine. I accidentally edited a temporary file with your result so the actually tested filed didn't get changed. It works with the first recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! @neallred